# ajax request does not pass to route in laravel 5.2

Tags: ajax, url, post, methods, laravel-5

I am trying to send post request to route form **script.js**

this is my script.js

```
$( "input[type=checkbox]" ).on( "click",function () {
alert('hello')
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url :"load_task",
    data: 1,
});
```

});

this is my route

```
Route::post('load_task',function (){
    return "funk you post";
});
Route::get('load_task',function (){
    return "funk you get";
});
```

I just need to update status of a checkbox in database,
what i am trying to do is  send ajax request when checkbox is clicked and update database from controller

but i am having trouble invoking route. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

url in the ajax is just a string. So it's just 'load_task'. But to hit the route you need something like `http://www.example.com/load_task`. Therefore you need to generate full url using `{{url('load_task'}}` and then pass it to the AJAX

**SUGGESTION**

Insert a new hidden input say `id="url"` and set generated url as its value.

```
<input type="hiddel" id="url" value="{{url('load_task'}}">
```

And pass its value as url in AJAX

```
$( "input[type=checkbox]" ).on( "click",function () { 
     alert('hello'); 
     $.ajax({ 
           type: "POST", 
           url : $("#url").val(), 
           data: 1,
      });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to have change 'load_task' to full url.
     example:
     https://domainyour/load_task